# Rails: Turbolinks triggers page reload when remote form is submitted

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a remote form to update some data in a Rails app:

```
%h4 Headline
= form_tag(object_update_path(@object.uid), method: :patch, remote: true, id: "update_form")
= render "form/select", name: "object[attribute]", label: false, options: @select_options, value: @select_value
.text-right
  = link_to 'submit', "#", :onclick => "$('#update_form').submit()"
  %button.btn-primary{ type: "submit" } Update
```

When clicking either the button or the link the form is first submitted, as ajax call, with

`Accept: */*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript`

in the request headers. Then the controller action is executed as expected and JSON is returned.

But after that the page reloads. The Chrome dev tools network console shows Turbolinks as initiator. Disabling Turbolinks by removing it from `application.js` stopped this behavior but removing Turbolinks is not an option right now.

Has anyone seen something like this before? How would I go about fixing this issue without removing Turbolinks?

I am using Turbolinks 2.5.3 and Rails 5.0.7

Comment: I'm seeing something similar on a side project I'm working on with rails, turbolinks and stimulusjs.